# Django redirect from one view to another WITH PARAMETERS

Tags: django, django-views

User submits form of Checkout in my e-commerce website, now I want him to redirect to index function directly.

```
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'shop/checkout.html')
    else:
        # ... DO SOME WORK ...
        response = redirect(index)
        return response
```

Above code snippet works fine, But when I do `response = redirect(index,msg="Order has been placed")`. I get error

Note that my Index Function has parameter msg defined.

```
def index(request, msg=False):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'shop/checkout.html')
    else:
        # ... DO SOME WORK ...
        msg="Order has been placed"
        return redirect('index', msg)



def index(request, msg):
    # do something with msg
```

Comment: I am getting error " Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name. " trying this.

Second, I can't delete default parameter of index because a normal user lands at index without any message. It is only after checkout that function with parameter is called.

Comment: it should be between ''

Comment: and make sure that you have included your app urls.py in main urls.py (in projects folder)